# Function methods .apply() .call() .bind()

Tags: javascript

I need help solving this;

```
let person = {
  firstname: "Benjamin",
  dog: {
    named: "Louie",
    owner: function() {
      return this.named + " is " + this.firstname + "'s dog'";
    }
  }
}

console.log(person.dog.owner.call(person)); // prints undefined is Benjamin's dog' instead of Louie is Benjamin's dog'
```

I know the call() method will refer to the person object which does not have the property - named.

Is there a way to use the bind() call() or apply() methods to print `"Louie is Benjamin's dog'"`

Comment: You need to access  correct property i.e. `return this.dog.named + " is " + this.firstname + "'s dog'";`

Comment: In the function, `this` can only have one value: it's either the `person` or the `dog`.

Comment: could have solved this easily yourself  with `console.log(this)` inside `dog.owner()`

Comment: `this` refers to `person` as you have passed person to `call(person)`. In your code `person.name` is `undefined`. So you need to change `this.named` to `this.dog.named`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `named` key is under `dog`. So call it `this.dog.named`

```js
let person = {
  firstname: "Benjamin",
  dog: {
    named: "Louie",
    owner: function() {
      return this.dog.named + " is " + this.firstname + "'s dog'";
    }
  }
}

console.log(person.dog.owner.call(person));
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.named` should be  `this.dog.named` because `named` property is inside `dog` object.

Check here:

```js
let person = {
  firstname: "Benjamin",
  dog: {
    named: "Louie",
    owner: function() {
      return this.dog.named + " is " + this.firstname + "'s dog'";
    }
  }
}
console.log(person.dog.owner.call(person));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function requires an object that has a `firstname` and a `named` property.

The only way to achieve what you want (without changing that function) would be to create a new object which has them and pass that to one of the functions you mentioned.

```
console.log(person.dog.owner.call({ firstname: "Benjamin", named: "Louie" }));
```